# How to re-trigger a process repeatedly in background in xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode5

I'am working on an application in xcode-5, I need to upload some data in background mode, I need a set of code to be repeated till the device terminates the background process. I  am able to do it once but I need to repeat again and again so that i can check the connectivity and perform the upload. I doing the same thing when the application comes in active mode.
Currently I'm using Timers with the following code :

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{
[bgrdTimer_ActiveMode invalidate];
bgrdTimer_ActiveMode=nil;

    self.backgroundTask=[application beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^{
        self.backgroundTask=UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
    }];

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT,0),^{

    bgrdTimer_BackGroundMode=[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:40.00 target:self selector:@selector(repeatUploadProcess_BackGroundMode) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

    });
 }


 - (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
 {
   [bgrdTimer_BackGroundMode invalidate];
   bgrdTimer_BackGroundMode=nil;
   bgrdTimer_ActiveMode=[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:40.00 target:self selector:@selector(repeatUploadProcess_ActiveMode) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
 }
```

repeatUploadProcess_ActiveMode and repeatUploadProcess_BackGroundMode are the methods containing the set of code which is suppose to be repeated

the problem is when I invalidate the bgrdTimer_ActiveMode the other timer dosn't gets invoked.

Comment: If any one has a better alternative solution which would fulfill my requirements then please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

Have you enabled the background fetch mode?    Click on the project target, and under the capabilities tab select "background fetch".

Theoretically you should also be setting [application endBackgroundTask:bgTask].  It sounds like you know, but if it never ends, iOS will end up killing your app.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Yes I have enabled the backgroundFetch. What I found out is the timer is not invoked when it was called inside dispatch async. So I initiated it outside an it worked fine and i also invalidated it inside beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^{}; both the timers are working as expected and the app dosnt crashes too,
But I have the intitution that its not the right and reliable way , so if you have any suggestions please help.